# Vector derivatives of vector functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to evaluate the expression

$$
{\partial \over \partial \mathbf a} \arctan(\mathbf{|a \times b| \over a^T b})
$$

where $ \mathbf {a,b} \in \mathbf R^3 $ are functions of nodal positions on a chain: $ \mathbf a = \mathbf {x_{i-1} - x_i} $ and $\mathbf{b=x_i - x_{i+1}}$.

This is a vector derivative of a scalar function so we expect to get a vector at the end (in fact, a force).

Making the small angle approximation we can say $\arctan \theta \approx \theta$, and then using the product rule we have

$$
{{{\partial \over \partial \mathbf a} (\mathbf{|a \times b|})}\over\mathbf a^T \mathbf b} + {{\partial \over \partial \mathbf a} (\mathbf a^T \mathbf b)^{-1} (|\mathbf a \times \mathbf b|)}
$$

Just looking at the first term for now:

$$
{\partial \over \partial \mathbf a} \mathbf{| a \times b |} = {\partial \over \partial \mathbf a}((\mathbf{a \times b})^T(\mathbf{a \times b}))^{1/2}\\
={1 \over 2 \mathbf {|a \times b|}} (({\partial \over \partial \mathbf a}(\mathbf{a \times b})^T)(\mathbf{a \times b})+ (\mathbf{a \times b})^T({\partial \over \partial \mathbf a}(\mathbf{a \times b})))
$$

Now the difficulty I'm having is that presumably $ {\partial \mathbf a^T \over \partial \mathbf a} = \mathbf I^{3\times3}$ which is a matrix, not a vector, and thus can't be crossed with $\mathbf b^T $, which is nonsensical. Is this correct, and if not, how do I proceed with the derivation?

Answer (score 0):

Use the identity
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}
\|a\times b\|^2
=
2(b\times(a\times b))^T
$$

so that

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}
\frac{\|a\times b\|}{a^Tb}
&=
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}
\left(
(\|a\times b\|^2)^{1/2}
\frac{1}{a^Tb}
\right) \\
&=
\frac{1}{a^Tb}
\frac{1}{2\|a\times b\|}
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}
\|a\times b\|^2
-
\frac{\|a\times b\|}{(a^Tb)^2}
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}(a^Tb) \\
&=
\frac{(b\times(a\times b))^T}{(a^Tb)\|a\times b\|}
-
\frac{\|a\times b\|b^T}{(a^Tb)^2}
\end{align}
$$
(I added the missing $a^Tb$ factor thanks to Ted Black's comment below).

I will also add that I am using the convention for $\partial / \partial a$ in which $\partial f(a) / \partial a$ is a row. This convention is designed so that the equation
$$f(a+h) = f(a) + \frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial a}h + O(|h|^2)$$
holds, assuming $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and $a,h$ are vectors written as columns.
You will also see a lot of other conventions. For example, there is the one that Ted mentioned, where $\partial f(a)/\partial a$ is a column. This convention is designed so that the equation
$$f(a+h) = f(a) + \left\langle\frac{\partial f(a)}{\partial a},h\right\rangle + O(|h|^2)$$
holds, where again $a,h\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are written as columns.
If you choose this convention, then the answers I gave need to be transposed.

Comment: you are missing the $1/(\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{b})$ factor in the first part. Also strictly speaking what you are calculating is $\partial/\partial \mathbf{a}^T$ since the differential is $d\mathbf{a}$ (you can see that since the partial derivative you have calculated is a transpose vector).

Comment: Hi @TedBlack. Thanks for your comment. I modified my answer according to your correction. Regarding the row/column conventions, a while ago I used to have a favourite one but now prefer to be agnostic. I needed to provide the answer in one form or another, so I chose the "numerator layout" convention (as it is called in [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Notation)).

Answer (score 0):

Denote
$$
c
=
\frac{\|\mathbf{a \times b}\|}{\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{b}}
=
\frac{\alpha}{\beta}
$$

Using Lagrange's identity
$\alpha^2
=
\|\mathbf{a}\|^2\|\mathbf{b}\|^2
-
\beta^2
$, it holds
$$
\alpha (d\alpha)
=
\|\mathbf{b}\|^2 \mathbf{a}^T (d\mathbf{a})
-
\beta (d\beta)
$$
Moreover
$d\beta = \mathbf{b}^T (d\mathbf{a})$.

From here
\begin{eqnarray*}
dc
&=&
\frac{1}{\beta} (d\alpha)-
\frac{\alpha}{\beta^2} (d\beta)\\
\frac{\partial c}{\partial \mathbf{a}}
&=&
\frac{\|\mathbf{b}\|^2}{\alpha \beta} \mathbf{a}
-
\left[
\frac{1}{\alpha}+
\frac{\alpha}{\beta^2}
\right]
\mathbf{b}
\end{eqnarray*}